# In learnr can you have exercise chunks with incorrect code?

Tags: r, r-markdown, learnr

I'm writing a learnr course, I want to provide students with faulty code for them to fix, or demonstrate an error. For example:

````
---
title: "coding - intro"
output:
  learnr::tutorial:
    progressive: true
    allow_skip: true
runtime: shiny_prerendered
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(learnr)
```


```{r code_intro_data_type_error, exercise = FALSE, exercise.eval = FALSE}
weeks <- 4
days_in_week <- "7"

# we now attempt to multiple a number by a string
total_days <- weeks * days_in_week
```
````

I'd ideally also like to output the error message:

> Error in weeks * days_in_week : non-numeric argument to binary operator

But because the code has an error in that chunk it refuses to compile the learnr script

Comment: Yes :) I want to use this as an example of what not to do in a learnr project.

Comment: You can set the chunk option `error=TRUE`, or `error=FALSE`, I never remember.

Comment: brilliant, thanks!, it's error=TRUE.
Do you want to add an answer for me to accept?